# How to get the second occurrence of a Regexp match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get two string from the following url, first is `-43.575285`, the second is `172.762549`

> http://maps.apple.com/?lsp=9902&sll=-43.575285,172.762549

I wrote a regexp pattern `re = /-?\d+\.\d{6}/;`

which only works for the first value, is there any way the matcher can continue search for the result string and give me the second pattern occurrence?

P.S I remember ruby has the `$1-$9` to reference the occurrence.

Comment: PS: Ruby's `$1`, `$2`, ... globals are for capture groups, not for matches within a string.

Comment: @muistooshort you are right at this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the `g` flag to the end...

```
re = /-?\d+\.\d{6}/g;
```

This `g` is for *global*.

```
var matches = str.match(re);
```

Note that this won't work quite like the above if you add capturing groups.

Comment: link to any documentation? what if you have one capturing group, but you want to reference several matches of that one group?

Comment: @Magne Keep calling `match()` until you get `null`, e.g. with a `while() {}` loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
var in="http://maps.apple.com/?lsp=9902&sll=-43.575285,172.762549";

var res=in.match(-?\d+\.\d{6}/g);
```

Now res is an array of matches. If you want second element,

```
res[1]
```

would get it for you.